# Android Tablet: working with external trackpad and touchpad(drawing)

Tags: android

i want to attach external trackpad with my android tablet, i want to do some drawing type stuff. 
can you pls help me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert your touchpad/trackpad in usb-host connector on tablet.