# can we simulate the touchpad or trackpad values to android tablet?

Tags: android, touch, usb

i Found this threaad usefull

[Android Tablet: working with external trackpad and touchpad(drawing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243253/android-tablet-working-with-external-trackpad-and-touchpaddrawing)

Is that possible to simulate the values that touchpad sending to the tablet or minipc

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Also, can you please specify which device do you have, and sample codes, maybe?

Comment: In android tablets usb devices like mouse keyboard, touchpad, trackpad are workings with usbhost manager, that means we can send the same values that usb devices sends to the android using usb

Comment: i'm working on a project to create capacitive touchpad to control android mini pc (usb stick) , for that i required the details about what type of data that touchpad will send to the android, ofcouse that will be the xy coordinates, i want to know more detailed about that

Comment: http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=101596  ::  related

Comment: I think my question is understandable and also i got the solution from @MilchePatern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, if you want to find this out at runtime, then you could use [InputManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/input/InputManager.html) and [InputDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html) to get properties of your input device.

These [two](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/touch-devices.html) [links](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html) should also be useful.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply

This is what the exact solution i expected